# How to access the request headers when using the deferred library on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I would like to access the `X-Appengine-*` headers. Are these completely hidden when using the deferred library?

[Actually I'm using flask and thus werkzeug, if that matters.]

Comment: What do you mean with access and which header? You can set headers using: _header. Fi: _headers = {'X-AppEngine-FailFast' : 'True'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's as simple as that:

```python
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
req = webapp.get_request()
```

Comment: I believe this only works for webapp2 - `webapp` has no such function. It works with python 2.7 runtime [because webapp2 is aliased to webapp](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#webapp2)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the OP wants to access the headers from the *original* request (the one that called defer()) inside the task that runs the deferred handler. Given that the deferred handler runs as a separate request, those headers are lost -- if you want them, you must grab them in the original request and pass them as arguments to the deferred function somehow.

Comment: What request do you actually get when you call `webapp.get_request()` as my own answer suggest?

Comment: @herr.kaste: you get the request that the task queue posted to your app (after deferred created and enqueued the task)